# Infragistics grid to excel issue

Tags: excel, infragistics

I have an MVC application in which I am using infragistics grid to display data(using EF to fetch data from database). I am able to export grid data to excel.. but I want to generate file with name mentioned in the code below..

Function exportexcel_click(){
Iggridexporter.exportgrid{
Filename: iggrid
}
}

Kindly assist.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You should provide to [`exportGrid`](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2019.1/ig.gridexcelexporter#methods:exportGrid) method your grid selector as first parameter, and `userSettings` as second parameter. Try to use code like this:

```
Function exportexcel_click(){ Iggridexporter.exportGrid( YOUR_GRID_SELECTOR, { fileName: iggrid }) };
```